# Как взять дочерний эелемент в Js

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var button = document.querySelectorAll('.but')
  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      var p1 = this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.firstChild.innerHTML;
      alert(p1);
    })

  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Текст который должен выдать alert </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Удалить</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="but">Редактировать</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Текст который должен выдать alert2 </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Удалить2</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="but">Редактировать2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Как мне при нажатии на элемент классом `but`, получить текст из первой ссылки своей группы `Текст который должен выдать alert`

Comment: Не понял вопроса...

Comment: При нажатии на .but Должен в alert выйти текст "Текст который должен выдать alert"

Comment: Понятно........

Comment: Ты хочешь, что бы он на прямую нашел или таких блоков может быть много, как он должен искать, в чем смысл?

Comment: Посмотри я правильно переформулировал твой вопрос?

Comment: Угу, только вот как получить этот текст

Comment: А нет, это все должно находиться в одной таблице! Я не заметил

Comment: А в примере, что в разных таблицах? Там одна таблица

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var p1 = this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.firstChild.innerHTML;
> ```

```
var p1 = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("a").textContent;
```

Код полностью:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var button = document.querySelectorAll('.but')
  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      var p1 = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("a").textContent;
      console.log(p1);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Текст который должен выдать alert </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Удалить</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="but">Редактировать</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Текст который должен выдать alert2 </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Удалить2</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="but">Редактировать2</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Но таким образом всегда берется только первое значение, тут вышла неправильная правка Это все должно находиться в одной таблице

Comment: Не понимаю. Поведение полностью соответствует описанному в вопросе. При нажатии во второй строке выводится из неё, а не из первой.

Comment: Все потому что у вас в коде все находиться в отдельных таблицах ,  а нужно что бы в одной, Air немного неправильно сделал правку вопроса

Comment: @emirlan1, поменял на одну таблицу, код остался тот же. Проверь уж там наконец, а?

Comment: @Qweriy смотрите  вы поставили class на саму ссылку а если поставить непосредственно на td То и будет выводить только 1 текст, как быть?

Comment: Я поставил так, как в твоём вопросе. Ты можешь сам посчитать, где там сколько parent'ов в твоей разметке?